# Unable to update my view's subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

Unable to update my view's subview

I am using a container view which has a scrollview, i am adding couple of other viewcontroller's view as subview to the scrollview. Below is the code for adding as subview to the scrollview.

```
for (int i = 0; i < tags.count; i++) {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        RMKeyDetailViewController *det = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RMKeyDetailViewController"];
        [self addChildViewController:det];
        frame.size = det.view.bounds.size;
        det.view.frame = frame;
        det.myTag = [tags objectAtIndex:i];
        [scrollView addSubview:det.view];
        [det didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    }

    pageControl.numberOfPages=tags.count;

    CGFloat statusBarHeight = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height;

    CGFloat navbarheight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat totHeight = statusBarHeight+navbarheight;

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * tags.count, scrollView.frame.size.height-totHeight);
```

Now, In RMKeyDetailViewController I am using UIImagePickerController to pick the image and update the imageview in RMKeyDetailViewController like below, but the picked images are not showing.

Can anyone suggest me a better approach to handle this scenario?

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    firstThumbImageView.image=image;
```

Comment: Why add `UIViewController` and not simply subviews?

Comment: It will be easy to handle webservices for each screen instance. so, i thought to use UIViewController to manage each view seperatly.

Comment: How did you eventually solve this?

Answer (score 0):

While you are loading the image into a `UIImageView` named **iv**, you must add **iv** to your view hierarchy.

Comment: "firstThumbImageView" is already in the view hierarchy, the given image is now visible in its place.

Comment: When i call RMKeyDetailViewController directly (not adding as subview into the scrollview) everything works perfetly.  Only the problem occurs while adding RMKeyDetailViewController's view as subview of my container scrollview